# How to remove auto statusbar color changed in android

Tags: java, android, colors, statusbar

Whenever i start my app. It changes statusbar colour into white colour. Which is not looking good. I don't want this. How to not auto change this colour it should be default colour or something else.

[image]

Comment: You can change the colorPrimary in your styles.xml.

Comment: changed but still it is white.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the theme of your activity to FullscreenTheme written below :

```
 <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

Copy and paste the above code to your styles.xml file

and modify the activity by copy and paste the code below before setContentView() method :

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: yes it worked by applying only style xml but i don't know how it works :-). any good reference to understand all these things ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly changing it to full screen , you can change the color in themes.xml  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecs69.png)

Also it is suggested that make your seperate color variables in the beginning of the project to make things easy later , as we use only variable name in our code , and then changing the color of whole project becomes easy. Instead of providing hard coded HEX values everywhere.